# What does the $this->db->select portion of the CI Active Record API do?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I have code like this:

```
$this->db->select('title')->from('entries')->where('id', 1);
$query = $this->db->get();
echo $query->row('title');
```

Which echoes the title from the entries table where the id is equal to 1.

Why doesn't it work without the 'title in row function?

```
echo $query->row();
```

As it returns the first row?

Why do I have to have 'title' in both places (`$query->row` and `$this->db->select`), in order for this to work? It doesn't make sense to me.

Can anybody explain how this works, supposedly provide with alternative ways to get the value from the database?

Comment: Because you may be selecting more than one field...?! I don't know the CI API, but `SELECT foo, bar, baz` is pretty typical in SQL. The above code just abstracts an SQL query. Maybe you should familiarize yourself with the underlying concepts?

Comment: When I write traditional functions without using the CI framework, this is exactly what I'm looking for: mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT title FROM entries WHERE id = 1"), 0);

Comment: Well, there you also provide `0` as argument for *which* column you want to return. In CI you do it using a column name, not index. I don't know if CI has the option to use indexes as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->db->select('title')->from('entries')->where('id', 1);
```

Generates

```
SELECT title FROM entries WHERE id = 1
```

$query retrieves the result in an array:

```
array( [0] => array( [title] => 'your title' ))
```

`row('title')` returns the title column from the first row of your result array.

The reason you need to tell it which column to get is because `row` and `get` can be used with many columns.

Comment: so could I just say row(0)?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Documentation is available here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

Comment: So it should theoretically be identical to say row(0) and row('title')? It's not returning the same result upon testing...

Comment: Sorry, I misread. If you give it a number, that is the row. E.g. the fifth row from the results array, row(5,'title'). So... use row(0,'title') instead, row('title') appears to assume it's row 0.